# Is it possible to loop through something while an exception remains? | Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was wondering if you could loop through an exception until it becomes false just like this:

```
try:
    get_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath')
except as ElementTime:
    while ElementTime is True:
        sleep(1)
        get_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is something like this:

```
while True:
    try:
        get_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath')
        break
    except as ElementTime:
        sleep(1)
```

You could also include a limit on the number of trials, by including a `count` variable and if it crosses a limit then you could break out of the loop. This would save you from an infinite loop in case the element at the xpath is not rendered.

```
count = 0
max_trials = 10 
while count < max_trials:
    try:
        max_trials += 1
        get_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('xpath')
        break
    except as ElementTime:
        sleep(1)
```